# on click edit button i am not getting value of shift start time and shift end time while editing

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).on("click", ".edit_record", function() {
    var edit_id = $(this).data('shift_id');

    $('#theTable tr:not(:first)').remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_task.php',
        data: {
            edit_id: edit_id,
            shift_edit: 'shift_edit'
        },
        success:function(data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
             
            $('#shift_name').val(response.shift_name);
            $('#shift_start_time').val(response.shift_start_time);
            $('#shift_end_time').val(response.shift_end_time);
            $('#shift_data_iud').val(response.shift_id);
        }
    });
    $("#insert-more").hide();
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Any one who can help me and thanks in advance